# Invalid nested resource added to collection before save in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

This is my routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
    resources :comments
end
```

And this is post/show.html.haml

```
.post
  %h1= @post.title
  %p= @post.content

  - @post.comments.each do |comment|
     .comment
        %h3= comment.name
        %p= comment.text

= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build])  do |f|
  = f.label :name
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.label :text
  = f.text_area :text
  = f.submit
```

The problem is that when I try to save an invalid comment it still gets added to @post.comments and printed out. If I do a refresh the invalid comment disappears, but still I want to avoid this if possible - and was wondering what the best practice is?

Currently I'm working around this issue by doing this check:

```
- unless comment.invalid?
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :-)

Comment: What does your save method look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone wants to know, I solved this problem in the following way:

```
= form_for([@post, @comment = @comment || @post.comments.build)
```

Comment: As a sidenote, this code belongs in your controller where you define your @comment.